# Opening a wallet with bitcoind

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am running bitcoind after previously running bitcoin-qt. I made a wallet with bitcoin-qt (and encrypted it) and I would like to open it now with bitcoind. The folder that contains the wallet.dat file is in the data directory, but when I run either of the following:

```
bitcoin-cli listwallets
bitcoin-cli getwalletinfo
```

it does not show my wallet. I have tried:

```
bitcoind -wallet="directory with wallet.data file"
```

and still no luck, it just tried to rund bitcoind and says it is already running (not sure why, I am running bitcoind -daemon).

Any idea how I can import this wallet?

Comment: Have you tried `bitcoin-cli loadwallet <wallet name>` where `<wallet name>` is the name of your wallet (i.e. the name of the directory containing the wallet.dat file)?

Answer (score 3):

Run RPC **listwallets** and check if your account is listed.

If not, run **loadwallet** with only account name:

(assuming directory on disk: /home/user/.bitcoin/wallets/accountname/wallet.dat)

Command: `loadwallet accountname`

Answer (score -1):

you must describe you bitcoin.conf , default was home folder user  .bitcoin

here i have some example BSV script for change defaut values such location wallet data block and etc.

[example script manage blockchain](https://github.com/sicute/blockchain)

you can check in bsv folder there was running custom script and example config .